# How to fix coefficients of multiple variables in a linear regression model using statsmodel in python?

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels

Suppose I have a dependent variable y and independent variables x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 and x6. I want to build a linear regression model using statsmodels in python. I also want to fix the coefficients of x2,x4 and x5 to 0.2,2 and 0.5 respectively in the model. How do I fix the coefficients in the model using statsmodels' OLS module in python?

Comment: Why don't you regress `y - 0.2*x2 - 2*x4 - 0.5*x5` with `x1`, `x3` and `x6` instead?